# How to check android device codename?

Tags: android

Some android devices (models) are released in many versions. I suppose they differ in their firmwares (ROM) which varies according to the region (and the carrier) it has been sold in. The question is how can I check whether my Samsung Galaxy S3 is md0, m0skt or maybe d2spr ? The best would be to check it programmatically. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class gives access to various device property strings.

Answer (score 0):

On my phone (HTC Incredible) it's just in Settings -> About Phone -> Phone Identity.